# can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python, int, concatenation

I put my coding in IDLE and got error message

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list.

Why the python doesn't accept index in `values[index]` as an `int`?
What should I do with this problem?

```
def repeat_elem (values, index, num_times):
    # this function returns a new list in which the element of 'values' 
    # at position 'index' has been repeated 'num_times' times
    return values[:index] + values[index]*(num_times - 1) + values[index+1:]
```

Comment: `values[index]` is a number. If you multiply it by another number, it is still a number. You need `[values[index]]`, which is a list consisting of one number.

Comment: what type do you think this: `values[index]*(num_times - 1)` is?

Comment: You could probably write it more elegantly using generators.

Comment: Why do you think `index` is the problem?

Comment: If you haven't already, try adding some debugging (see if each value works, and mark the one giving you the problem) my guess would be that values[index]*(num_times - 1) is the problem, as your value at index*num_times -1 (which is an int) can't be added to values[:index]; were you trying to get: values[(index*num_times-1)]?  Best of luck!

Comment: Thx guys.It perfectly work now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def repeat_elem (values, index, num_times):
    # this function returns a new list in which the element of 'values'
    # at position 'index' has been repeated 'num_times' times
    return values[:index] + ([values[index]] * num_times) + values[index+1:]
```

In the code above:

- `repeat_elem([1, 2, 3], 0, 5)` returns `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`
- `repeat_elem([1, 2, 3], 1, 5)` returns `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]`
- `repeat_elem([1, 2, 3], 2, 5)` returns `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: The `()` are redundant as the `*` is higher precedence that the `+`